# How to replace the contents of nsx file index from dbf in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dbf, dbase, clipper

I have updated replace items with SQL in the DBF database but the DOS display of the item used in transactions cannot be selected and edited so the solution I have to replace the contents in the NSX file, which is the index of the DBF file.
How can I replace index file contents from dbf with vb.net?

Thanks

DBF database IFG.DBF is the master data item

INDEX DBF database IFGX.NSX is the master data item

DBF database GSD.DBF is the detailed sales data

INDEX DBF database GSDX.NSX is the detailed sales data

ITEM BEFORE REPLACE:
[image: ITEM BEFORE REPLACE]

ITEM AFTER REPLACE:
[image: ITEM AFTER REPLACE]

```
Private Sub updatepathdbfIFG()
   Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Concat("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV"))
            Dim tableDBF = "IFG"
            cn.Open()
 Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE " & tableDBF & " SET " & "ITM=?" & "WHERE ITM=? AND ITC=?", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ITM", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxnewitem.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ITM", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxolditem.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ITC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxITC.Text
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
   cn.Close()
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("updated table IFG", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Sub

 Private Sub updatepathdbfGSD()
Using cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Concat("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV"))
            Dim tableDBF = "GSD"
            cn.Open()
   Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE " & tableDBF & " SET " & "ITM=?" & "WHERE ITM=? AND ITC=?", cn))
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ITM", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxnewitem.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ITM", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxolditem.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ITC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxITC.Text
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
    cn.Close()
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("updated table GSD", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Probably Jet driver is not compatible with those Clipper files. This has nothing to do with (Visual) Foxpro. Please remove those tags referring to foxpro. You named the two parameters same. Use different parameter names, they are only for you, OleDb use the positional arguments and don't care those names

Comment: @CetinBasoz , Thank you for your feedback. Thank you for your feedback. The problem I mean is that there is no update index file (. NSX) so that in the transaction in the dos item that I replace if I edit then the item is blank. The sql I use can only update dbf files only. Well I will remove foxpro tag

Answer (score 1):

The .NSX extension for .DBF files was a proprietary Clipper extension called *HyperSix*. It not only used a different file format for Clipper index files (.nsx instead of .cdx), but also a different MEMO format (.smt) which allowed memo file sizes to up to 2GB in size *(at the time)*.

You require a proprietary commercial ADO provider to work with these databases: [Apollo ADO.NET Data Provider](https://www.apollodb.com/apollo_net.asp)